# Matrix multiplication inside function causes error messages

Tags: r, vector, matrix-multiplication

```
compute.ret <- function
(
 rl, # risk-level
 cm, # matrix
 weights # market weights
)
{
  ret <<- as.numeric(rl) * cm %*% as.numeric(weights)
  return(ret)
}     
compute.ret(rl, mat, mkt)
```

`rl` is a constant number, and if I define `mat` as a single k*n matrix and `mkt` as a single k*1 vector this function works perfectly fine. However, if I define `mat` as a list containing multiple different k*n matrices and `mkt` as a list containing multiple different k*1 vectors for different periods, I receive the following error message:

> Error in compute.ret(rl, mat, mkt) :    (list) object cannot be
>   coerced to type 'double'

If I try to define the `cm` and `weights` inside the function as a matrix and a vector, I get the following error message:

> Error in as.matrix(cm) %*% as.vector(weights) :    requires
>   numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

I have defined `mat` and `mkt` as follows:

```
    #For the first period
    mat <- cov(returns[2:100,])
    mkt <- mkt.pct[100,]

    #For multiple periods
    mat <- lapply(100:nrow(returns), function(y) cov(returns[2:y,]))
    mkt <- lapply(100:nrow(mkt.pct), function(y) Mkt.pct[y,])

    #risk-level is constant:
    rl <- 5

#dput(head(returns,2)) 
    structure(list(DNB = c(0.114243002653732, 0.195422174486189), 
        `NORSK HYDRO` = c(0.1122798949739, -0.00460120398819178), 
        ORKLA = c(0.161921233302634, 0.0975985380644365), STOREBRAND = c(-0.0104598710465411, 
        0.134080646470034), ATEA = c(0.230813685612872, 0.0833298658193907
        ), `SCHIBSTED A` = c(0.175083182810205, 0.025055387901995
        ), BONHEUR = c(0.122042954064391, 0.0685451093572719), EKORNES = c(0.0308399733914992, 
        0.387914655275288), `KONGSBERG GRUPPEN` = c(0.146331747503733, 
        0.144545571434711), `TOMRA SYSTEMS` = c(0.229735097295185, 
        0.113694123289024), VEIDEKKE = c(0.0956482232945592, 0.127761864415601
        ), `ARENDALS FOSSEKOMPANI` = c(-0.00490324849781087, 0.0300289375740116
        ), `OLAV THON EIEP.` = c(0.149949369069503, 0.124473689874361
        ), `PETROLEUM GEO SERVICES` = c(0.143132959750097, 0.0775223758035154
        ), `SPAREBANK 1 SR BANK` = c(0.116836172780265, 0.136008691393096
        ), `STOLT-NIELSEN` = c(0.0203245318798289, 0.105361175863283
        ), `ODFJELL 'A'` = c(0.0928105116601813, 0.0951529274561497
        ), `SPAREBANK 1 NORD-NORGE` = c(0.101567028883779, 0.0178314553554076
        ), `SPAREBANK 1 SMN` = c(0.0737988562169507, 0.0494500632192766
        ), `WILHS.WILHELMSEN HDG.'A'` = c(0.0183315120772754, 0.056632199816499
        ), `NORDEA BANK (~NK)` = c(-0.0453314420778795, 0.148848639131562
        ), `ATLAS COPCO 'A' (~NK)` = c(0.0248312597721068, 0.0290019908934364
        ), `VOLVO 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.0731428324040068, 0.0809789583310443
        ), `SANDVIK (~NK)` = c(0.0215711016815666, 0.0478190202909319
        ), `SWEDBANK 'A' (~NK)` = c(-0.00387080379817896, 0.175104194416416
        ), `ERICSSON 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.0867095270438493, 0.0422849025158128
        ), `SVENSKA HANDBKN.'A' (~NK)` = c(-0.112150502158686, 0.106884133216956
        ), `HENNES & MAURITZ 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.0699802466749088, -0.0165562560357835
        ), `SEB 'A' (~NK)` = c(0.0241105004437796, 0.100514480686855
        ), `INVESTOR 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.0901067257894706, 0.0720965788285361
        ), `SWEDISH MATCH (~NK)` = c(0.0495931153170738, 0.00673046936294565
        ), `ELECTROLUX 'B' (~NK)` = c(-0.0159231362522644, 0.0948956647849578
        ), `SKANSKA 'B' (~NK)` = c(-0.0149499928083486, 0.0559276474130345
        ), `SCA 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.0153704546006071, 0.112653682679431
        ), `SECURITAS 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.0859336634195991, -0.0157794854084339
        ), `HOLMEN 'B' (~NK)` = c(-0.0103328627361939, 0.15208408056624
        ), `SSAB 'A' (~NK)` = c(0.0775964977767735, -0.00139032020103993
        ), `ERICSSON 'A' (~NK)` = c(0.0883253562867765, 0.0455789424195976
        ), `INVESTOR 'A' (~NK)` = c(0.0927668419378803, 0.0658048552831031
        ), `VOLVO 'A' (~NK)` = c(0.0676940440190063, 0.0844327289446728
        ), `NOVO NORDISK 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.00836898160564752, 0.111705492228705
        ), `DANSKE BANK (~NK)` = c(0.0320936491074429, 0.161716610294261
        ), `COLOPLAST 'B' (~NK)` = c(-0.0485797018299386, 0.0971342879304209
        ), `CARLSBERG 'B' (~NK)` = c(-0.00952448228427664, 0.0481822504669644
        ), `A P MOLLER - MAERSK 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.134842700281774, 
        0.101913237684838), `TDC (~NK)` = c(0.0252955834254122, 0.100036296355213
        ), `TOPDANMARK (~NK)` = c(0.0492085405235308, 0.0885565764800388
        ), `WILLIAM DEMANT HLDG. (~NK)` = c(-0.0328990626156782, 
        0.0970785204593115), `JYSKE BANK (~NK)` = c(0.0260312437317136, 
        0.155304805452083), `KOBENHAVNS LUFTHAVNE (~NK)` = c(0.067217427832867, 
        0.0305874626848826), `NKT (~NK)` = c(-0.0201934852148808, 
        0.170861427458748), `ROCKWOOL 'B' (~NK)` = c(-0.00151625629222524, 
        -0.021101011531117), `SYDBANK (~NK)` = c(0.109683728491056, 
        0.0495161923681742), `FLSMIDTH & CO.'B' (~NK)` = c(0.0798367466050992, 
        0.0261601909079402), `GN STORE NORD (~NK)` = c(0.0244859713531514, 
        0.0854282276786818), `ALK-ABELLO (~NK)` = c(-0.0396520859817241, 
        0.0808896077540951), `BANG & OLUFSEN 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.00304894573872123, 
        0.220052552386606), `SANTA FE GROUP (~NK)` = c(0.291329154090765, 
        0.0472354961961209), `CARLSBERG 'A' (~NK)` = c(-0.00700101105484289, 
        0.0359347297366485), `ROCKWOOL 'A' (~NK)` = c(-0.0245025749334355, 
        -0.00139537865863981), `NOKIA (~NK)` = c(0.126441684721964, 
        0.00769527210049607), `SAMPO 'A' (~NK)` = c(0.0940079555690148, 
        0.155713195034335), `KONE 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.0376163345061415, 
        0.0457195380715649), `UPM-KYMMENE (~NK)` = c(0.00115990210766144, 
        0.0609824011070531), `WARTSILA (~NK)` = c(0.0329251954092374, 
        0.0762362885269973), `METSO (~NK)` = c(-0.0276370997573922, 
        0.158750156652548), `STORA ENSO 'R' (~NK)` = c(-0.0058540569153482, 
        0.0970682931630558), `HUHTAMAKI (~NK)` = c(-0.00284777905703818, 
        0.0224783334681041), `FINNAIR (~NK)` = c(0.0442869319742045, 
        0.0525404295882317), `KEMIRA (~NK)` = c(-0.104316294022408, 
        0.0465316047015052), `UPONOR (~NK)` = c(0.0458579624296079, 
        0.0802649812687683), `KESKO 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.0217802707650036, 
        0.115006843859385), `ORION 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.0483993278432202, 
        0.0446430392461813), `OUTOKUMPU 'A' (~NK)` = c(0.0173239680759633, 
        0.0354718724242646), `RAISIO (~NK)` = c(0.244082260408811, 
        0.177805383079262), `TIETO OYJ (~NK)` = c(0.104391540656928, 
        0.0204030283840117), `METSA BOARD 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.0133698481269666, 
        0.179810871730302), `ORION 'A' (~NK)` = c(0.0223035782719256, 
        0.0332939199192042), `STOCKMANN 'A' (~NK)` = c(0.0155244469329926, 
        0.038305372243036), `STORA ENSO 'A' (~NK)` = c(-0.0200792186174187, 
        0.103131677314942)), .Names = c("DNB", "NORSK HYDRO", "ORKLA", 
    "STOREBRAND", "ATEA", "SCHIBSTED A", "BONHEUR", "EKORNES", "KONGSBERG GRUPPEN", 
    "TOMRA SYSTEMS", "VEIDEKKE", "ARENDALS FOSSEKOMPANI", "OLAV THON EIEP.", 
    "PETROLEUM GEO SERVICES", "SPAREBANK 1 SR BANK", "STOLT-NIELSEN", 
    "ODFJELL 'A'", "SPAREBANK 1 NORD-NORGE", "SPAREBANK 1 SMN", "WILHS.WILHELMSEN HDG.'A'", 
    "NORDEA BANK (~NK)", "ATLAS COPCO 'A' (~NK)", "VOLVO 'B' (~NK)", 
    "SANDVIK (~NK)", "SWEDBANK 'A' (~NK)", "ERICSSON 'B' (~NK)", 
    "SVENSKA HANDBKN.'A' (~NK)", "HENNES & MAURITZ 'B' (~NK)", "SEB 'A' (~NK)", 
    "INVESTOR 'B' (~NK)", "SWEDISH MATCH (~NK)", "ELECTROLUX 'B' (~NK)", 
    "SKANSKA 'B' (~NK)", "SCA 'B' (~NK)", "SECURITAS 'B' (~NK)", 
    "HOLMEN 'B' (~NK)", "SSAB 'A' (~NK)", "ERICSSON 'A' (~NK)", "INVESTOR 'A' (~NK)", 
    "VOLVO 'A' (~NK)", "NOVO NORDISK 'B' (~NK)", "DANSKE BANK (~NK)", 
    "COLOPLAST 'B' (~NK)", "CARLSBERG 'B' (~NK)", "A P MOLLER - MAERSK 'B' (~NK)", 
    "TDC (~NK)", "TOPDANMARK (~NK)", "WILLIAM DEMANT HLDG. (~NK)", 
    "JYSKE BANK (~NK)", "KOBENHAVNS LUFTHAVNE (~NK)", "NKT (~NK)", 
    "ROCKWOOL 'B' (~NK)", "SYDBANK (~NK)", "FLSMIDTH & CO.'B' (~NK)", 
    "GN STORE NORD (~NK)", "ALK-ABELLO (~NK)", "BANG & OLUFSEN 'B' (~NK)", 
    "SANTA FE GROUP (~NK)", "CARLSBERG 'A' (~NK)", "ROCKWOOL 'A' (~NK)", 
    "NOKIA (~NK)", "SAMPO 'A' (~NK)", "KONE 'B' (~NK)", "UPM-KYMMENE (~NK)", 
    "WARTSILA (~NK)", "METSO (~NK)", "STORA ENSO 'R' (~NK)", "HUHTAMAKI (~NK)", 
    "FINNAIR (~NK)", "KEMIRA (~NK)", "UPONOR (~NK)", "KESKO 'B' (~NK)", 
    "ORION 'B' (~NK)", "OUTOKUMPU 'A' (~NK)", "RAISIO (~NK)", "TIETO OYJ (~NK)", 
    "METSA BOARD 'B' (~NK)", "ORION 'A' (~NK)", "STOCKMANN 'A' (~NK)", 
    "STORA ENSO 'A' (~NK)"), row.names = 2:3, class = "data.frame")

#dput(head(Mkt.pct,2))
    structure(list(DNB = c(0.0130911031863844, 0.0148436443461116
    ), `NORSK HYDRO` = c(0.0656202028062552, 0.060983838741199), 
        ORKLA = c(0.0157059383874119, 0.0161601293815974), STOREBRAND = c(0.00797050065007084, 
        0.00850323028627703), ATEA = c(0.00174625378791056, 0.00177198576286123
        ), `SCHIBSTED A` = c(0.00732288011104105, 0.00700863433828195
        ), BONHEUR = c(0.00252070586866636, 0.00251956609171883), 
        EKORNES = c(0.000946154462841077, 0.00130004244856961), `KONGSBERG GRUPPEN` = c(0.00118371896832389, 
        0.00127609728965736), `TOMRA SYSTEMS` = c(0.0035652668350741, 
        0.00372753152033644), VEIDEKKE = c(0.000989241833288067, 
        0.0010488933009586), `ARENDALS FOSSEKOMPANI` = c(0.00111913526141214, 
        0.00107655674335278), `OLAV THON EIEP.` = c(0.0016431202999304, 
        0.00173644571995502), `PETROLEUM GEO SERVICES` = c(0.00673959864366955, 
        0.00679696353383315), `SPAREBANK 1 SR BANK` = c(0.0011331504939971, 
        0.00121132435136855), `STOLT-NIELSEN` = c(0.00293774584412645, 
        0.00304923447363627), `ODFJELL 'A'` = c(0.00152003720160408, 
        0.00155990426043415), `SPAREBANK 1 NORD-NORGE` = c(0.000910122057445298, 
        0.000864717259377188), `SPAREBANK 1 SMN` = c(0.000942240298785819, 
        0.000924070451131194), `WILHS.WILHELMSEN HDG.'A'` = c(0.00137174878071225, 
        0.00135496596927216), `NORDEA BANK (~NK)` = c(0.0286748896677251, 
        0.0310448801949994), `ATLAS COPCO 'A' (~NK)` = c(0.0147325426053798, 
        0.014159480185436), `VOLVO 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.0380824093624216, 
        0.0385424504764243), `SANDVIK (~NK)` = c(0.0274705187491339, 
        0.0269020010085569), `SWEDBANK 'A' (~NK)` = c(0.0232605669980714, 
        0.0258531443770606), `ERICSSON 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.147959094491921, 
        0.144169856176502), `SVENSKA HANDBKN.'A' (~NK)` = c(0.0288306986497957, 
        0.0299494020090758), `HENNES & MAURITZ 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.0272859690705124, 
        0.0250578644115827), `SEB 'A' (~NK)` = c(0.0244360078250768, 
        0.0252140983228561), `INVESTOR 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.025860187464626, 
        0.0259389069155966), `SWEDISH MATCH (~NK)` = c(0.00857693566046275, 
        0.00806038785730358), `ELECTROLUX 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.0208092033865695, 
        0.0213555908169106), `SKANSKA 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.0252236623180593, 
        0.024897530854419), `SCA 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.0141970202526503, 
        0.0148227134170042), `SECURITAS 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.0106139108269937, 
        0.0097541503230873), `HOLMEN 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.00926214322246672, 
        0.0100609857162177), `SSAB 'A' (~NK)` = c(0.00824783022142955, 
        0.00769026830605565), `ERICSSON 'A' (~NK)` = c(0.0140974142471957, 
        0.0137714512687781), `INVESTOR 'A' (~NK)` = c(0.0179665890901973, 
        0.017910040128126), `VOLVO 'A' (~NK)` = c(0.0166912502737251, 
        0.0169517570686256), `NOVO NORDISK 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.0292245771907756, 
        0.0304804344949926), `DANSKE BANK (~NK)` = c(0.021474769105159, 
        0.0235529643446683), `COLOPLAST 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.00408057915928444, 
        0.00419512583639377), `CARLSBERG 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.00931366656342796, 
        0.00912251150027678), `A P MOLLER - MAERSK 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.0157048020172023, 
        0.0162280778953254), `TDC (~NK)` = c(0.0173613851475325, 
        0.0179019141752701), `TOPDANMARK (~NK)` = c(0.00241780123302007, 
        0.0024663587018541), `WILLIAM DEMANT HLDG. (~NK)` = c(0.00373297613850623, 
        0.00383763524797797), `JYSKE BANK (~NK)` = c(0.00345383153139609, 
        0.00376353359846821), `KOBENHAVNS LUFTHAVNE (~NK)` = c(0.00501413096084276, 
        0.00482603126995735), `NKT (~NK)` = c(0.00212372598398948, 
        0.00235050520251664), `ROCKWOOL 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.00223220988170647, 
        0.0020406775812588), `SYDBANK (~NK)` = c(0.00188848945914436, 
        0.00185196186023889), `FLSMIDTH & CO.'B' (~NK)` = c(0.00541980723420693, 
        0.00519344461488411), `GN STORE NORD (~NK)` = c(0.00306333842666562, 
        0.00311373605790372), `ALK-ABELLO (~NK)` = c(0.00301973811133235, 
        0.00305568096511678), `BANG & OLUFSEN 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.00285217085417642, 
        0.00331530075852983), `SANTA FE GROUP (~NK)` = c(0.00266960982342172, 
        0.00261259651769184), `CARLSBERG 'A' (~NK)` = c(0.0114906204436931, 
        0.0111184450035804), `ROCKWOOL 'A' (~NK)` = c(0.00319547302936972, 
        0.00297912246162981), `NOKIA (~NK)` = c(0.0669832551982801, 
        0.0630171384266337), `SAMPO 'A' (~NK)` = c(0.00611072821309801, 
        0.00666190990401108), `KONE 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.00281647778155156, 
        0.00275191113903857), `UPM-KYMMENE (~NK)` = c(0.0280138852128935, 
        0.0277911327959644), `WARTSILA (~NK)` = c(0.00383901368368869, 
        0.00386678013665095), `METSO (~NK)` = c(0.00667914217022736, 
        0.00730364749675182), `STORA ENSO 'R' (~NK)` = c(0.0043575851807918, 
        0.00448110363934146), `HUHTAMAKI (~NK)` = c(0.0039143613417524, 
        0.00373719025671851), `FINNAIR (~NK)` = c(0.00306533496599219, 
        0.00301550590216998), `KEMIRA (~NK)` = c(0.00745529091483776, 
        0.00729035848359746), `UPONOR (~NK)` = c(0.00257306570436523, 
        0.00260210171756828), `KESKO 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.00409924246168501, 
        0.00429142717840808), `ORION 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.00431466353100038, 
        0.00421128973539609), `OUTOKUMPU 'A' (~NK)` = c(0.0105198998665294, 
        0.0101745217055348), `RAISIO (~NK)` = c(0.00472191020486253, 
        0.00526236120241807), `TIETO OYJ (~NK)` = c(0.00388740411511377, 
        0.0037037990443058), `METSA BOARD 'B' (~NK)` = c(0.00380089004144887, 
        0.00424439492600249), `ORION 'A' (~NK)` = c(0.00491468278458397, 
        0.00474303360888234), `STOCKMANN 'A' (~NK)` = c(0.00250731406140473, 
        0.00243184540389359), `STORA ENSO 'A' (~NK)` = c(0.00443444010767518, 
        0.00458775310362995)), .Names = c("DNB", "NORSK HYDRO", "ORKLA", 
    "STOREBRAND", "ATEA", "SCHIBSTED A", "BONHEUR", "EKORNES", "KONGSBERG GRUPPEN", 
    "TOMRA SYSTEMS", "VEIDEKKE", "ARENDALS FOSSEKOMPANI", "OLAV THON EIEP.", 
    "PETROLEUM GEO SERVICES", "SPAREBANK 1 SR BANK", "STOLT-NIELSEN", 
    "ODFJELL 'A'", "SPAREBANK 1 NORD-NORGE", "SPAREBANK 1 SMN", "WILHS.WILHELMSEN HDG.'A'", 
    "NORDEA BANK (~NK)", "ATLAS COPCO 'A' (~NK)", "VOLVO 'B' (~NK)", 
    "SANDVIK (~NK)", "SWEDBANK 'A' (~NK)", "ERICSSON 'B' (~NK)", 
    "SVENSKA HANDBKN.'A' (~NK)", "HENNES & MAURITZ 'B' (~NK)", "SEB 'A' (~NK)", 
    "INVESTOR 'B' (~NK)", "SWEDISH MATCH (~NK)", "ELECTROLUX 'B' (~NK)", 
    "SKANSKA 'B' (~NK)", "SCA 'B' (~NK)", "SECURITAS 'B' (~NK)", 
    "HOLMEN 'B' (~NK)", "SSAB 'A' (~NK)", "ERICSSON 'A' (~NK)", "INVESTOR 'A' (~NK)", 
    "VOLVO 'A' (~NK)", "NOVO NORDISK 'B' (~NK)", "DANSKE BANK (~NK)", 
    "COLOPLAST 'B' (~NK)", "CARLSBERG 'B' (~NK)", "A P MOLLER - MAERSK 'B' (~NK)", 
    "TDC (~NK)", "TOPDANMARK (~NK)", "WILLIAM DEMANT HLDG. (~NK)", 
    "JYSKE BANK (~NK)", "KOBENHAVNS LUFTHAVNE (~NK)", "NKT (~NK)", 
    "ROCKWOOL 'B' (~NK)", "SYDBANK (~NK)", "FLSMIDTH & CO.'B' (~NK)", 
    "GN STORE NORD (~NK)", "ALK-ABELLO (~NK)", "BANG & OLUFSEN 'B' (~NK)", 
    "SANTA FE GROUP (~NK)", "CARLSBERG 'A' (~NK)", "ROCKWOOL 'A' (~NK)", 
    "NOKIA (~NK)", "SAMPO 'A' (~NK)", "KONE 'B' (~NK)", "UPM-KYMMENE (~NK)", 
    "WARTSILA (~NK)", "METSO (~NK)", "STORA ENSO 'R' (~NK)", "HUHTAMAKI (~NK)", 
    "FINNAIR (~NK)", "KEMIRA (~NK)", "UPONOR (~NK)", "KESKO 'B' (~NK)", 
    "ORION 'B' (~NK)", "OUTOKUMPU 'A' (~NK)", "RAISIO (~NK)", "TIETO OYJ (~NK)", 
    "METSA BOARD 'B' (~NK)", "ORION 'A' (~NK)", "STOCKMANN 'A' (~NK)", 
    "STORA ENSO 'A' (~NK)"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"

)
```

Comment: If `mkt` is a list, then `weights` will be a list as well.  You can't coerce a list to a numeric vector in general, only in special cases.  You should probably select a particular element from `mkt`, e.g. `compute.ret(rl, mat, mkt[[1]])`.  Similar issues likely arise with the other arguments, but you didn't give us a reproducible example to check.

Comment: @user2554330 the problem in selecting a particular element is that I want to run the function on 100+ observations, so it would be quite tedious to specify each particular element every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do matrix multiplication between lists of conformable matrices just by writing `%*%` as R will just see that you are feeding lists to the matrix multiplication function. But you can re-write your function to take a list of matrices and weights as arguments and compute the result.

I am assuming here that you want to feed the function a list of matrices `mat = [m1, m2, ...]` and weights `[w1, w2, ...]` and output `compute.ret(r1, m1, w1)`. If this is the case it can be done with `mapply()`:

```r
compute.ret <- function(rl, # risk-level
  cm, # matrix
  weights # market weights
){
  ret <- as.numeric(rl) * cm %*% as.numeric(weights)
  return(ret)
}     

mat <- matrix(rnorm(10), 5, 5)
mkt <- c(1:5)
r1 <- 10

compute.ret(r1, mat, mkt)
#>             [,1]
#> [1,]  -59.448779
#> [2,]   22.676986
#> [3,] -120.041254
#> [4,]    7.958607
#> [5,]  -30.035787

# vectorized version
compute.ret.vec <- function(rl, cm, weights) {
  ret <- mapply(cm, weights, FUN = function(a,b){r1 * a %*% b})
  ret
}

mat.ls <- list(mat, mat)
mkt.ls <- list(mkt, mkt)

compute.ret.vec(r1, mat.ls, mkt.ls)
#>             [,1]        [,2]
#> [1,]  -59.448779  -59.448779
#> [2,]   22.676986   22.676986
#> [3,] -120.041254 -120.041254
#> [4,]    7.958607    7.958607
#> [5,]  -30.035787  -30.035787
```

Here we are computing the matrix product for the first matrix and first weights, second matrix and second weights, etc. The multiplicative constant is assumed to be a single value as in description.

Created on 2018-05-21 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: what you describe is the output that I am looking for....however when I tried your new code, it still gave me the requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments error message

Comment: @Quant if you copy all the code I posted and paste it into your console does it produce two columns of output? It runs fine for me, which makes me think the problem might be in the data structures you are feeding to the function.

Comment: I tried copying and running your code, it did produce two colums of output. However, when I substitute it with my own data it does not work.....might it be because I used lapply to define mat and mkt for multiple periods?

Comment: @Quant that shouldn't matter -- if I simulate fake data using `lapply()` it works fine. If you post some of your data using `dput()` it should be possible to figure out the problem. If you edit your question by pasting in `dput(head(returns))` and `dput(head(Mkt.pct))` I'll take a look.

Comment: @Quant ok its a dimensions problem: when you pull rows out of your Mkt.pct data-structure since its a data.frame they come out as row-vectors with dimensions 1 X k, whereas when you pull a row from a matrix it does not have a dimension and will always be conformable as long as it is the right length. The error arises because you cannot multiply a K x K object and a 1 x K object, you need K x K times K x 1. Inside `compute.ret.vec` change `a %*% b` to `a %*% t(b)` and it should work.

Comment: thank you so much, it seemed to work perfectly fine now!

Comment: @Quant great! If you don't mind you can accept my answer by clicking the green check mark next to it, and upvotes are appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately not allowed to give upvotes, as I dont have enough reputation